# String Math Algebra for greater than 2^31_2^63 numbers

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, codeblocks, algebra

This is a 2 Part Question...(C/C++)

**FIRST PART**

The Idea:
I'm looking for a library that can do algebra on strings, practically can some, subtract, multiply, etc etc any virtual number, of any precision(only limited by memory).

The "maybe" solution:
I keep searching on web and everyone says to use the The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (at gmpi.org) wich is a unix based library(so they say) but is capable of working on windows(The SO i'm using, so they say).

> GMP's main target platforms are Unix-type systems, such as GNU/Linux,
>   Solaris, HP-UX, Mac OS X/Darwin, BSD, AIX, etc. It also is known to
>   work on Windows in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

I started by doing some of it by myself, just to get an idea, but since i don't whant to reinvent the weel  i tryed to explore the cln capabilitys on my SDK (Code::Blocks v12.11)

**SECOND PART:**

Starting of with some examples, i tried to make a console project with the pi.cc file...
I did what they told me [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) but i keep getting an no such file or directory error, and changing the path or the compiler options (improvising what i shoudn't) the Program(SDK) crashes...

I did global compiler settings:

Compiler path:

> C:\Users\Mr.D2\Dropbox\SourceCode Importado\Matemática\cln\include

Linker path(is that the .c files?, i think not):

> C:\Users\Mr.D2\Dropbox\SourceCode Importado\Matemática

Here is a picture: [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/ylo0.jpg/)

Also i would like to ask,

Knowing that #include <...> indicates that the path is specified in the compiler, and
             #include "..." its a project file

What does it mean the

[EDIT]

```
    "#include <cln/real.h>"
```

mainly  the cln/ notation?

I think that is all

Comment: Generally, when you specify a compilation, you give a directory or directories where include files can be found.  Sometimes, the directory will contain a subdirectory - cln, for example.

Comment: don't know any library, but IMO write some code yourself to do algebra on strings is not very hard